# Different results generating SHA256 hash with .Net and react native library (same input)

Tags: c#, react-native, sha256

In .Net I'm generating a hash this way:

```
Convert.ToBase64String(SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("123456")));
```

The result is: "jZae727K08KaOmKSgOaGzww/XVqGr/PKEgIMkjrcbJI="

Now I'm generating a hash in a React Native app with this [library](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-sha256):

```
import { sha256 } from 'react-native-sha256';
return await sha256('123456');
```

And the result is: "8d969eef6ecad3c29a3a629280e686cf0c3f5d5a86aff3ca12020c923adc6c92"

Not sure what I'm doing wrong...

**EDIT**:

Final solution (thanks Martin Backasch):

```
var inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("123456");
var hashBytes = SHA256.Create().ComputeHash(inputBytes);
return BitConverter.ToString(hashBytes).Replace("-", string.Empty).ToLower();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result from the library is `HEX`.
You have to convert it to `Base64`

Try it [here](http://tomeko.net/online_tools/hex_to_base64.php?lang=en).

Input:

```
"8d969eef6ecad3c29a3a629280e686cf0c3f5d5a86aff3ca12020c923adc6c92"
```

Output:

```
"jZae727K08KaOmKSgOaGzww/XVqGr/PKEgIMkjrcbJI="
```

---

You can convert your C# result from `Base64` to `HEX` by using the example given by [microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.convert.frombase64string(v=vs.110).aspx) or as a quick snippet:

```
var yourResult = Convert.ToBase64String(SHA256.Create()
                                              .ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8
                                                                   .GetBytes("123456")));

var apiResult = "8d969eef6ecad3c29a3a629280e686cf0c3f5d5a86aff3ca12020c923adc6c92";

var yourHexResult = BitConverter.ToString(Convert.FromBase64String(yourResult))
                                .Replace("-", string.Empty)
                                .ToLower();

Debug.Assert(yourHexResult == apiResult, "yourHexResult != apiResult");
```